# How to find the execution time of a method of the class under test using Junit?

Tags: junit, annotations, performance-testing

I need to find the execution time of methods and document them in a report to identify the execution times of different methods. This has to be done regularly, so whenever tests run in build the execution time is recorded.

One approach is to capture start and end time and take difference. Is there a way where we can annotate the method under test and only when the method is executed from Junit, the execution time is recorded?

For example:

```java
@Test 
public void test() { 
    classUndetTest.method1(); 
} 

void method1(){ 
  method2(); 
} 

void method2() { 
}
```

I would like to find the time taken for executing `method2`, when the test is run.

Comment: What is the meaning of "execution time is recorded"?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? If your goal is to benchmark the methods, you probably need to take a different approach.

Comment: what I meant was for eg:

@Test
public void test() 
 {
classUndetTest.method1();
}

void method1(){
method2();
}
void method2()
{
}

I would like to find the time taken for executing method2, when the test is run.

Comment: I need to find the execution time of methods and document them in report to identify the execution times of different methods.This has to be done regularly so whenevr tests run in build the execution time is recorded.

Comment: In your real code, does `method1()` do anything else other than call `method2()`? If it does, then it will be impossible to observe the time taken for `method2()` by observing the time taken for `method1()`.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you want, but maybe helpful: [JUnit Stopwatch](http://junit.org/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/Stopwatch.html).